# My gmail script stopped working and now I can not find it to delete it

Tags: google-apps-script

I continually get notifications stating that I have a script error. When I go to google docs to try to find the spreadsheet it is no longer there so I can not fix it or delete it. I am sick of getting script error emails all day long. How can I stop this???

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try
>   again." Count: "24"
>
> Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End 9/18/12 8:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/18/12 8:26 PM
>
> 9/18/12 9:26 PM   activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/18/12 9:26 PM
>
> 9/18/12 10:26 PM  activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/18/12 10:26 PM
>
> 9/18/12 11:26 PM  activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/18/12 11:26 PM
>
> 9/19/12 12:26 AM  activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/19/12 12:26 AM
>
> 9/19/12 1:26 AM   activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/19/12 1:26 AM 9/19/12
>   2:26 AM   activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please
>   wait a bit and try again. time-based  9/19/12 2:26 AM 9/19/12 3:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 3:26 AM 9/19/12 4:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 4:26 AM 9/19/12 5:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 5:26 AM 9/19/12 6:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 6:26 AM 9/19/12 7:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 7:26 AM 9/19/12 8:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 8:26 AM 9/19/12 9:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 9:26 AM 9/19/12 10:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 10:26 AM 9/19/12 11:26
>   AM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 11:26 AM 9/19/12 12:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 12:26 PM 9/19/12 1:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 1:26 PM 9/19/12 2:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 2:26 PM 9/19/12 3:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 3:26 PM 9/19/12 4:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 4:26 PM 9/19/12 5:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 5:26 PM 9/19/12 6:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 6:26 PM 9/19/12 7:26
>   PM    activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a
>   bit and try again.    time-based  9/19/12 7:26 PM

Comment: Is there any other information about the script, e.g. script key available? We can look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way that I know of to search for spreadsheet-contained scripts, which I agree is a nuisance.

There is an  [open issue in the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1639&q=scripts%20searchable&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)  for this, you might like to star it, which is kind of like voting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies you know the spreadsheet the errors are coming from. Is it in your Trash?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your script runs every hour or so, have you checked your triggers?  Normally your should find a time based trigger calling a function from this script, if it's the case you can simply delete it and the error won't happen anymore.